# Can't open csv file in "excel format"

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code to create a CSV file.

```
with open('CSV\globalLS', 'a', newline = "") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL )
    writer.writerow([name, datetime.datetime.now().date(), openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice, closePrice])
```

However, once the file is created and I try to open it - using `computer` - the file type is listed as `bigdEal` and the file opening default setting - excel - is not shown.

It opens fine using notebook but it needs to be in an excel file.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the extension in the filename you are writing to:

```
with open('CSV\globalLS.csv', 'a', newline = "") as f:
```

This way, when you try and open the file, your operating system will be able to apply the default application used for `.csv` type.

If your default application is not set correctly for csv files, you need to set this yourself. The process will be dependent on your operating system.